# IIS is taking lot of time to deliver first javascript and image file

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net

We have a Content Management Application and when we did the testing using a load runner we saw very good performance (pages were rendered less than 2 seconds (most of them in milliseconds).

But now we are monitoring the application with various tools and we noticed that the first session of the user is taking a lot of time (like 50 seconds) and when we check the first javascript and the first image loads in about 20 to 30 seconds each. It is always the first javascript and first image (how small the file size is, I swapped the file order and see the same behavior) I am not sure where to start the debugging. Any help where to start the debugging will be highly appricated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see the same behavior when serving the static files from a 'static' application pool? Do you use the integrated pipeline and have all your static files processed by some managed modules?

Comment: This is the handler I have to process the static files  
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />